# need property is of 4 animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

the code is ok but when i move my mouse blue arrow is coming back and normally and hover effect doesn't work again. height need to be auto and fixed speed . i don't know what to do pls help.
this the page and my problem http://www.redmanproduction.com/webtest/tour.html

```
$('.tur-maindiv').toggle(
function(){
    $('.tur-imgcorner').css('background-image', 'url(img/turbtnorangebothup.png)');
},

function(){
    $('.tur-imgcorner').css('background-image', 'url(img/turbtnorangebothl.png)');
});
```

second part is

```
 $(".tur-maindiv").toggle(function() {
$('.tur-maindiv').addClass("current").css('border-color', 'rgba(255,101,70,1.00)');
$(".tur-box1").animate({
    height: auto (how to fix the speed of animation )
});
```

third part

```
$(".tur-maindiv").removeClass("current").css('border-color', 'rgba(131,200,222,1.00)');
$(".tur-imgcorner").removeClass("current").css('background-image', 'url(img/turbtnorangebothup.png)');
$(".tur-box1").animate({
    height: 102
});
```

i need 3 script for this ? or how can i use one code for all ? thanks for help.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. As it is it cannot be understood at all. And add a sample of your HTML code too!

Answer (score 0):

will try to provide answer according to my understanding of your problem

Let's start with the hover effect

Let say your parent element is the div with an id 'tur-maindiv' (note that I prefer to select by the id of the element and not the class)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tur-maindiv').hover( function() {
     // when user hovers over the main div
     $(this).css('background-image', 'url(img/turbtnorangebothup.png)');
  },
  function(){
     //when user hovers out
     $(this).css('background-image', 'url(img/turbtnorangebothl.png)');
  }
  );
});
```

Now for the show hide functionality when the user clicks on the div.

```
$('#tur-maindiv')click(function(){
   $(this).toggle('slow', function(){$(this).addClass("current").css('border-color', 'rgba(255,101,70,1.00)');
   $(".tur-box1").animate({
    height: 281
    });       
  });
```

Comment: thnk you in the beginning . but i need couple of thinks in t he same time.

Comment: There are two things that you are trying to do. 1) do something during the mouse hover event, 2) on click of the main div element hide/show something. The code that I provided adds two event handlers, one for 'hover' and one for 'click' events. Let me know what part of my code is not working.

Comment: I recommend you use an online code playground like http://jsfiddle.net . There you can add your html, javascript and html. Once you do this it will be easier for the community to help correct your code. Of course make sure you share you new 'fiddle'/code example with us

Comment: i m not a cooder simple designer and trying to learn. i cooperate couple of codes thats why looks complicated . difficult to understand  pls check this link http://www.redmanproduction.com/webtest/tour.html in the first box you will see my problem. this for your help